# Workbooks added by Workbook.Add command is not visible in task bar

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am facing a very weird problem wherein, I am creating a new workbook using the below code, but the new workbook thus created, is not visible and it is not even showing up in the taskbar.
The code lies in a powerpoint file.

```
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add
 Application.Visible = msoTrue            ' Forcing this also doesn't solve
```

The same issue is happening with the code of opening an excel with the following code

```
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(fullpath)  ' full path is the path to existing excel file
Application.Visible = True                 ' Forcing this also doesn't solve
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help is much much appreciated. Here is what I have tried

1. Made sure the excel library references is added.
2. Used the `Application.Visible = True` in code
3. Have even restarted the system multiple times.
4. Tried to set Excel -> Options -> Advanced -> Show All Windows in the Taskbar check box, as suggested in forums, but didn't find this option in excel though.

Comment: `Application` is the Powerpoint instance, not Excel.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen for quick response. So do I have to use, Excel.Application.Visible = true instead ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a workbook in an already open instance of Excel?

Comment: It worked. Putting in Excel.Application.visible = true worked. Thank you so much. I have wasted nearly four hours scratching my head on this.